# Why does AppBarButton draw emoji wrong

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

When I add an AppBarButton with Content="☺" to a Universal app and run it on Windows 8.1 it shows up, when I run the same thing in Windows Phone 8.1 all I get is a white circle where the emoji should be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the default font in Windows Phone doesn't have that glyph. Try referencing the font in the FontFamily property in XAML. The Segoe UI Symbol font should have a smily glyph. It's also recommended to use the following convention for using custom font glyphs (instead of the Content property):

```
<AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE170;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

More info can be found here [MSDN - Quickstart: Adding app bar buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj662743.aspx)

Comment: Content="☺" works and displays the correct color emoji if I do it to a textblock anywhere else in the application. Your answer shows the non color version of the emoji.

Comment: TextBlocks are different controls, different controls use sometimes different properties. ☺ should work too of course if you paste it in the Glyph property in my example, I just prefer using the Unicode ID. And for using the color version just copy and paste the glyph or the Unicode ID of the glyph you want and it should work. The color versions wont work in the appbar if I recall correctly though. (at least not without some style overrides)

Comment: PS: I don't know about the other Segoe fonts, but I think the color version isn't available in the Segoe UI Symbol font, I know for sure Segoe UI WP does have the color version though.